# Identify the sql statements using python

Tags: python, sql

The task is to identify if the SQL statements is a DML / DDL  or not.

So I had to use an array and push all the DML/DDL patterns into that and search for them by iterating.

Below is a simple code snippet where

1. I am sending an SQL query as a parameter
2. Check if it has update, alter, drop, delete
3. Print

```py
def check_dml_statementent (self,sql)
    actions = ['update', 'alter', 'drop', 'delete']
    for action in actions
    if ( re.search (action,sql.lower() ) :
        print "This is a dml statement "
```

But there are some edge cases, for which I need to code for

- To consider

  ```sql
  Update table table_name where ...
  alter table table_name
  create table table_name
  delete * from table_name
  drop table_name
  ```
- Not to consider:

  ```sql
  select * from table where action='drop'
  ```

So, the task is to identify only SQL statements which modify, drop, create, alter table etc.

One specific idea is to check if an SQL statement starts with above array values using `startswith` function.

Comment: This is probably one of those cases where you should elaborate more on **why** you want to do that. My spidey senses tell me that this is not something you should do.

Comment: I think you have your definition backwards.  DML statements simply add/update/remove rows in a table (i.e. INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, etc.).  They do **not** alter the table structure.  Perhaps you meant DDL, not DML?

Comment: Whatever it is you're doing, you're probably better off creating a user with read-only permissions on the database and let that execute the statement. The database will check if the user is authorized to modify data and will block these kinds of operations more effectively than you'll be able to do it ;-) - Google SQL injection and whitelisting/blacklisting keywords to learn more.

Comment: @Maurice  Actually , the requirement is just to log the information and not block the statements , just that we should know which user ran it.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [python-sqlparse](https://pypi.org/project/sqlparse/) for that:

```python
import sqlparse

query = """
select * from table where action='delete';
delete from table where name='Alex'
"""

parsed = sqlparse.parse(query)
for p in parsed:
    print(p.get_type())
```

This will output:

```
SELECT
DELETE
```